# php insert textarea value without \n\r

Tags: php

When insert `textarea` value into `db` it convert user `enter` to `\n\r` and when i want to show this value on site it also show with `\n\r` in view and also in submit i tried to convert this chars but not works. i submit my form via `jquery ajax`.

```
$safetext = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["describtion"]);
$safetextformat = nl2br($safetext);
```

result:

> sdfsdf\r\nsdf\r\nsdf\r\nsdf\r\nsdf\r\ns\r\ndf\r\nsdf\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nsdf\r\nsdf\r\n\r\nsdf

Also tried `preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $yourString );` but still not working. how can i avoid this?

**Update:** The process of submiting and displaying is as follows:

**Insert/Html**

```
<textarea id="describtion" name="describtion" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

**Insert/Jquery**

```
var data = new FormData();
params = $('#add-form').serializeArray();

$.each(params, function(i, val) {
data.append(val.name, val.value);
});

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: ..,
and etc..
});
```

**PHP**

```
$sql = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO ads (text) 
VALUES (?)');

$sql->bind_param("s",$safetext);
$sql->execute();
```

**result in db:**

> sdfsdf\r\nsfsdf\r\n\r\nsdfsdfsdfsdf sd fs
>   dfsdf\r\n\r\nsdf\r\n\r\nds\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nsdfsdf

**Now in edit page:**

I get data directly from `db` as `array` and showing each data with `for each` and the code:

```
<textarea id="describtion" name="describtion" class="form-control"><?=nl2br($ed['text']);?></textarea>
<div><?=$s = str_replace("\r\n","<br>",$ed['text'])?></div>
```

**Broswer result is:**

[image]

Comment: Use `nl2br` when showing.

Comment: If you want to store it as `<br>` instead of `\r\n`, call `nl2br` **before** `mysqli_real_escape_string` because the second function will escape the slash in `\n` and `\r`.

Comment: @u_mulder i tried this but not wroking `<textarea id="describtion" name="describtion" class="form-control"><?=nl2br($ed['text']);?></textarea>`

Comment: In textarea there's no need to use `nl2br`.

Comment: @rickdenhaan now result is `test<br />\r\ntest<br />\r\n<br />\r\ntest test<br />\r\n<br />\r\ntest<br />\r\ntest`

Comment: @martian which is fine for displaying, because browsers do not display the "\r\n" part.

Comment: @rickdenhaan no, i the result from textarea when showing, not db

Comment: `<textarea id="describtion" name="describtion" class="form-control">test&lt;br /&gt;\r\ntest&lt;br /&gt;\r\n&lt;br /&gt;\r\ntest test&lt;br /&gt;\r\n&lt;br /&gt;\r\ntest&lt;br /&gt;\r\ntest</textarea>` look, browser still show these.

Comment: Then you should just store the value in the database without modifications, and only use `nl2br` if you're displaying the value somewhere that's not in a textarea

Comment: I showing textarea in edit page, where user can edit the textarea @rickdenhaan

Comment: then why are you trying to remove the `\r\n` from it?

Comment: @rickdenhaan Because browser show `\r\n` on textarea instead of show text in new line. also i tested `nl2br` on a div like this: `<div><?=nl2br($ed['text']);?></div>` still show `\r\n` , but the goal is textarea.

Comment: @rickdenhaan see updated answer with screen shot, above is textarea and below is div, on both it shows `\r\n`

Comment: Based on that screenshot I'd say that wherever you get the text from has it stored incorrectly; it has "\r\n" stored as four characters: (`"\\" + "r" + "\\" + "n"`) instead of two (`"\r" + "\n"`).

Comment: Well, any suggest to avoid this? i mentioned `php` part in my question, and jquery part is `$('#add-form').serializeArray();` and regular ajax post, I am wonder. Does jquery cause this problem? @rickdenhaan

Comment: jQuery should not cause this problem. What happens in PHP after you receive the post request? How does the text go from the jQuery post to the textarea in the edit page?

Comment: @rickdenhaan Please see updated answer.

Comment: @martian the html and javascript is probably not the problem. What happens in PHP?

Comment: @rickdenhaan i found the problem, when i remove `mysqli_real_escape_string` it worked. Now i have two problem, what should i do instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string` , 2. now result in browser in textarea is: `test<br />
test<br />
test<br />
<br />
test<br />
test`

Comment: It's `\r\n`, not `\n\r`

Comment: @rickdenhaan second problem solved, i removed `nl2br` from `textarea` but at the end, what should i do with `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: @martian depends on why you were using it in the first place. You still haven't showed the PHP code you are using after that.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I mentioned my `PHP` code at first, I get text like this `$safetext = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["describtion"]);` then some code that not related to this, then INSERT into db. that's all.

Comment: Yes, it's the code that does the INSERT that's **very** important. Are you using a prepared statement for that?

Comment: @rickdenhaan yes, updated in answer, but shorten.

Comment: @martian that's what I wanted to know. By using a prepared statement **combined** with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, you are **double-escaping** the value, since `bind_param()` **also** escapes the string. If you're using a prepared statement, you **must not** use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to avoid exactly the problem you were having.

Comment: Much appreciated, i didn't know this. @rickdenhaan

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably more complicated and in different step...

It seems that you are putting into database literal string `'blalba\r\nblabla'` and this is incorrect in your case. `mysql_real_escape_string()` escapes that to `'blalba\\r\\nblabla'` ...

The solution would be to:

Insert a string to database using proper `double` quotes: `"blalba\r\nblabla"`

PS. In `textarea` proper new line character is `"\n"`, not `<br />`. So all the solutions with `nl2br()` are simply wrong.

PPS. `mysql_real_escape_string()` should be used only when inserting to database, not when reading from it.

Comment: I fully understood your explanation but just one thing, use double quotes where exactly? see my php part in question. where you mean i should put double quotes

Comment: convert the string to <br> before you put it in the DB then you dont have to worry about the slashes. If you need to convert back (using str_replace()) you can do it post DB

Answer (score -1):

Use str_replace. Example:

```
    $s = str_replace("\r\n","<br>",$s);
```

You can convert it before you store it or after; you can alway go back and forth as needed.